# Elasticsearch facets missing even though I'm pretty sure a match exists

Tags: elasticsearch, faceted-search, facet

I have an index of papers which include facets by topic, author, resource type, etc.

Users are allowed to filter the results by one of the facet values. When this happens, for some reason some of the other facets disappear, even when I know for sure that there should be some matches.

For example, I know that John Smith has written 5 papers on the subject of Ecology. So when I filter by term Ecology, I should see John Smith under the author facet. Instead, the author facet is completely empty, and the `missing` value now is a large number where before it was a small number. Meanwhile, plenty of other facets still have values.

Here is what the mapping looks like:

```
{
  "myindex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "paper" : {
        "properties" : {
          "author_name" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "description" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "pub_date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "YYYY-MM-dd"
          },
          "pub_type" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "source_data" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "code" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              },
              "title" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "topics" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the sample query:

```
{
    "facets": {
        "history": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "pub_date",
                "interval": "year"
            }
        },
        "authors": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "author_name",
                "size": 10
            }
        },
        "topics": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "topics.raw"
            }
        },
        "record_types": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "pub_type"
            }
        },
        "sources": {
            "nested": "source_data",
            "terms": {
                "field": "source_data.code"
            }
        }
    },
    "suggest": {
        "didyoumean": {
            "term": {
                "field": "title",
                "size": 100
            },
            "text": "*"
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "topics.raw": "Educational Technology"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50
}
```

When I run the same query without the filter, I get 10 items for each facet. When I run it with the filter, I get zero results for the facets `history`, `authors` and `record_types`.

I tried applying the `facet_filter` to each facet but this appeared to have no effect — or, at least, it did not increase the number of records returned by these facets.

Comment: Can you give an example record that you expect to be included in the facet count, but isn't (ie with topics.raw=Educational Technology and an author field)?

Comment: It appears to be showing up now. My best guess is there was some issue with the mapping that resolved when I did a reindex of some of the records. I'll keep my eye on it and post more information when I find out anything.